# Display custom post counts for author , not default posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, author, count

```
<?php    
global $wp_query;    
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();    
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type =     photoshop_tutorial' AND post_status = 'publish'");    
?>

<p>Post Count: <?php echo $post_count; ?></p>
```

I've tried with this codes & it shows the whole `photoshop_tutorial` posts count, but what I want is to display for individual author's posts, because I want to add it in author page.

For example:

> Smith posted `<?php $post_count; ?>` photoshop tutorials

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried fetching the requested posts with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query)?

```
$posts = new WP_Query();
$posts->query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'author' => $curauth->ID,
    'post_type' => 'photoshop_tutorial'
) );

$post_count = sizeof( $posts->posts );
```